# Algorithm to approximate Chaitin's Constant?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request

I'm searching for a good quantum algorithm to approximate [Chaitin's Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaitinsConstant.html). Any references/resources will do?

Note: This number is [uncomputable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant#Uncomputability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any quantum algorithm to approximate Chaitin's constant (or any other number) will also yield a classical algorithm to approximate that same number, just by simulating the quantum computer. (It won't be a *great* classical algorithm, but it's still an algorithm.)

As Chaitin's constant provably doesn't admit such a classical algorithm, it also doesn't admit a quantum algorithm either.

Comment: I was hoping to compare runtimes. Hence I wanted an explicit algorithm.

Comment: Run times to achieve... what? And to compare against... what?

Comment: You are right. I was hoping for some sort of algorithm which would guess a digit and tell you approximately where it was in the string of digits. Not sure if it is possible though (I was assuming it existed) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57116/430082